# pre('save') or pre('validate') doesn't trigger | Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

`pre('save')` or `pre('validate')` does not trigger when I save the data. Although, it is saving the data without triggering the pre function. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({...});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

userSchema.pre('save', function(next){ // tried with pre('validate')
    console.log('triggered...');
    next();
});

// adding a user
module.exports.addUser = function(user, callback){
    var newUser = new User(user);
    newUser.save(callback);
    //or
    User.create(user, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks only work if you define them *before* creating the model:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({...});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next){ // tried with pre('validate')
    console.log('triggered...');
    next();
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with async you need to define it with `true` option.

```
userSchema.pre('save', true, function(next){ // tried with pre('validate')
    console.log('triggered...');
    next();
});
```

You can look at [HERE](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) parallel and serial examples.

Comment: @TalhaTemuri Which version of mongoose do you use?

Comment: mongoose@4.11.1